# How can I upload an image to mongodb using multer module

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I'm new to nodeJs and I'm trying to upload an image to MongoDB through multer module. The backend server image.js works fine when I test through postman. But when I want to upload an image from the front end I couldn't. Any possible suggestion for this.

**This is image.js**

```
let express = require("express");
let app =express();
let mongodb = require("mongodb");
let assert = require("assert");
let createClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
let dbUrl = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/images";
let multer = require("multer");


let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,'images');
    },
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.fieldname+'_'+Date.now()+'.jpg')
    }
});
let upload = multer({storage:storage});

let imageup = express.Router().post('/',upload.single('image'),(req,res)=>{
    createClient.connect(dbUrl,(err,db)=>{
        assert.deepStrictEqual(null,err);
        insertDocuments(db,'images'+req.file.filename,()=>{
            db.close();
            res.json({'message':"file upladed successfully"});
        })
    })
})
let insertDocuments = function(db,filepath,callback){
    let collection = db.collection('users');
    collection.insertOne({filepath:filepath},
    (err,result)=>{
        //.deepStrictEqual(err,result);
        callback(result);
    });
}

module.exports = imageup;
```

**This is server.js file,**

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let port = 8080;
app.listen(port);

app.use('/imageup',require("./image"));

console.log(`server listening to port ${port}`)
```

**This is service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})

export class imageupService{
    constructor(public http:HttpClient){}
    public imageupload(data:any):Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/imageup",data)
    }
}
```

**This is image.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { imageupService } from "../services/imageupservice";
@Component({
  selector: 'imageup',
  templateUrl: './imageup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./imageup.component.css']
})
export class ImageupComponent implements OnInit {

  public file:any;
  constructor(public service:imageupService) { }
  public saveimage(data:any){
    this.service.imageupload(data).subscribe((posRes)=>{
      if(posRes.message =="file upladed successfully")
      {
        console.log("File uploaded successfully");
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**This is HTML file**

```
<p>Upload Image</p>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" [(ngModel)]="file">
<button (click)="saveimage({'filepath':file})">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the binary of an image directly in MongoDB is a really bad choice.

This practice eats up your storage space really quickly and the queries will be very slow.

Multer is designed in a way that allows you to upload the file to a storage local (the server itself) / remote (e.g. AWS S3). What you should do is to store the URL (for remote storage) or the path (local: like any static assets [css, js]) in MongoDB instead of the image as a whole.

You should then render the image on your page using the URL to the remote storage (e.g. https://bucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com/you_image.jpg)

or your server (https://yousite.com/assets/your_image.jpg)

Comment: Even though I think that the best approach is using storage like AWS S3 or local storage, if MongoDB is mandatory, the OP could use the BinData format as suggested in the following [post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gridfs-making-file-uploading-to-mongodb/)